# getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when trying to connect to oracle db

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

i am facing a problem getting OCI JDBC to work.
i need to use the oci driver because you cannot set a new password on logon when it has expired and is in grace time.

i use oracle 11g release 2

i downloaded the basic instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.4.0 and unzipped it. its located in the folder
`C:\Users\Yeslan to the Coa\workspace\KWIKI\instantclient_11_2\`.
i have added this link as it is to the `PATH`system variable.

i set the native library location in eclipse to that path.

when i try to logon to oracle:

```
protected static OracleConnection con;
static String url = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@//192.168.97.10:1521/orcl";
static String user = "user";    
static String pw = "password";

public final Connection openCon() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try {
        System.out.println("openCon():  URL = " + url + " username = "
                + user + " password = " + pw);
        prop.setProperty("user", user);
        prop.setProperty("password", pw);
        con = (OracleConnection) DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("oracle con ok");
        return con;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        String errMessage = e.getMessage();
        System.out.println("oracle con not opened because: " + errMessage);
    }
}
```

i get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Yeslan to the Coa\workspace\KWIKI\instantclient_11_2\ocijdbc11.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection$1.run(T2CConnection.java:3560)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.loadNativeLibrary(T2CConnection.java:3556)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.logon(T2CConnection.java:269)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CConnection.<init>(T2CConnection.java:165)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T2CDriverExtension.getConnection(T2CDriverExtension.java:53)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at at.nje.DB_FTP_Operations.ConnectOrcl.openCon(ConnectOrcl.java:76)
at at.nje.Kone.GUI.AdminFrame.<init>(AdminFrame.java:60)
at at.nje.Kone.GUI.AdminFrame$1.run(AdminFrame.java:46)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

please tell me what i am missing to do, or what i´m doing wrong.
How to set up oci jdbc on win 7 64 to connect to oracle 11g release 2

Comment: You need to make sure you are using the right natives for your java version. If the natives are for java 1.7 x64, then your application has to be run on java 1.7 x64 (meaning the JVM version), and vice versa. Double check that the drivers you are using match the JVM you are using.

Comment: "Can't find dependent libraries", the dll is loaded, but it is unable to locate its dependencies.

Comment: how can i set those missing dependencies?